# Finding the ranks of generalized eigenvectors given a Jordan normal form

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank, jordan-normal-form

Let $A$ be a $7\times 7$ matrix over $\mathbb{C}$ with minimal polynomial $m(t) = (t-1)^3(t-2)^2$.

One possible Jordan canonical form of $A$ that I found, up to similarity, is
$$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0 & & & &  \\
0 & 1 & 1 & & & &   \\
0 & 0 & 1 & & & &   \\
  &   &   & 2 & 1 &  \\
  &   &   & 0 & 2 &  \\
  &   &   &   &   & 2 & \\
  &   &   &   &   &   & 2
\end{pmatrix}$$
where the empty spaces are filles with zeros.

**Question** How would one go about finding the ranks of $(A-I)^k$ and $(A-2I)^k$ for $k \in \mathbb{Z}_+$?

My initial guess is that the rank of $(A-I)^k$ is 3 since that $3\times 3$ block is an invertible matrix, while the rank of $(A-2I)^k$ is $2$ since the $2\times 2$ block is invertible as well.

I know that a generalized eigenvector $v$ has rank $r$ if $(A-\lambda I)^r v = 0$ but $(A - \lambda I)^{r-1} v \neq 0$; but we don't know what $A$ is, so I can't use this here.

However, I did notice that if we let $B = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 0\\ 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$, then $(B-I)^i \neq \mathbf{0}$ for $i = 1,2$, but $(B-I)^3 = \mathbf{0}$, where $\mathbf{0}$ is the $3\times 3$ zero matrix.  But I don't know if this observation has anything to do with this problem or that it's just a coincidence.

Thank you for your help

Comment: When calculating powers of matrices in Jordan normal form, you can treat each Jordan block separately and find its rank. Then just add the ranks. Note that if $A$ is in JNF, then so is $A-\lambda I$ for all $\lambda$.

Comment: There are 3 different possibilities for the characteristic polynomial which in turn leads to 5 different JNF. The Generalized Cayley Hamilton theorem gives immediately the ranks of the operators of the corresponding factors in the minimal polynomial.